# One-to-One bi-directional mapping with composite primary key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mapping, one-to-one, composite-primary-key

Could someone please help me with doing the bi-directional one-to-one JPA mapping for the following relationship using the composite primary key using Hibernate/JPA?
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an `@Embeddable` to map the composite primary key of both entities and a `@MapsId` annotation on the address attribute of your `User` entity to share the primary key.

But before I show you the mapping, please be aware that `User` is a reserved word in most databases. I recommend you choose a different name for the entity. In my example, I changed it to `Person`.

Let's start with the `@Embeddable` that maps the primary keys. I named the class `AddressKey`. It's a simple Java class that implements the `Serializable` interface and has the attributes `xId` and `yId`. You also need to implement the `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

```
@Embeddable
public class AddressKey implements Serializable {

    private Long xId;
    private Long yId;

    public AddressKey() {}

    public AddressKey(Long xId, Long yId) {
        this.xId = xId;
        this.yId = yId;
    }

    // omit getter and setter for readability

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((xId == null) ? 0 : xId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((yId == null) ? 0 : yId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        AddressKey other = (AddressKey) obj;
        if (xId == null) {
            if (other.xId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!xId.equals(other.xId))
            return false;
        if (yId == null) {
            if (other.yId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!yId.equals(other.yId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you annotate the attribute with `@EmbeddedId`, you can use the `AddressKey` embeddable to map the primary key of the `Address` class.

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    @EmbeddedId
    private AddressKey id;

    private String city;

    private String street;

    private String country;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private Person person;

    // omit getter and setter methods
}
```

The mapping of the `Person` entity looks similar. In addition to the primary key mapping, you need to annotate the `address` attribute, which maps the association to the `Person` entity, with `@MapsId`. That tells Hibernate that it shall use the primary key of the associated `Address` entity as the primary of the `Person` entity.

You also need to annotate the `address` attribute with 2 `@JoinColumn` annotations to map the foreign keys to the `xId` and `yId` columns of your Person table. Without these annotations, Hibernate would map them to the columns `address_xId` and `address_yId`.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @EmbeddedId
    private AddressKey id;

    private String name;

    private String society;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="xId", referencedColumnName="xId")
    @JoinColumn(name="yId", referencedColumnName="yId")
    @MapsId
    private Address address;

    // omit getter and setter methods for readability
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Thorben. Just 2 questions I've got. **1)** Should it not be `@JoinColumns` at the `address` field in the `Person` entity, like `@OneToOne @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name="xId", referencedColumnName="xId"), @JoinColumn(name="yId", referencedColumnName="yId")}) @MapsId private Address address;` **2)** Is `@MapsId` really needed?

Comment: Hi Skip,

1) Since Hibernate 5.2 and JPA 2.2, the [`@JoinColumn` annotation is repeatable](https://thoughts-on-java.org/benefits-repeatable-annotations-hibernate-5-2/) and you no longer need to wrap it in a @JoinColumns annotation. 

2) Yes, `@MapsId` is required to tell Hibernate that it shall use the primary key value of the associated `Address` entity as the primary key value of the `Person` entity

Comment: @ThorbenJanssen Can we somehow make xId to be autogenerated using IDENTITY strategy (MySQL 5.7)?

Comment: Had a similar case with @OneToOne with composite and shared primary key by two entities, just that it was unidirectional.
So it didn't work until I labelled @MapsId with the name of the shared key (named "key" in my case:

```public class EnterpriseGroupsDetailsEntity{
  @EmbeddedId
  private GroupKey key;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name =.., referencedColumnName =.., insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @JoinColumn(name =..,
  @MapsId("key")
  private GroupEntity groupEntity;
...
```